# Python terminal call doesn't load appropriate libraries

Tags: python, subprocess, openmpi

I am running a program which utilizes the OpenMPI libraries on Fedora 20.

When I run the command from terminal:

```
../bin/boxfit ../settings/boxfitsettings.txt | tee boxoutput.log
```

it is successful.

When I run it through the Python console I return an error:

```
os.system('../bin/boxfit ../settings/boxfitsettings2.txt | tee boxoutput.log')

../bin/boxfit: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_cxx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same error results with

```
subprocess.call(args,shell=True)
```

I have the paths set the same so it should have access to the same libraries. Is there internal Python functionality that I need to be aware of to get around this error? Or is it perhaps an program compilation error that says the program libraries can't talk to Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it checks for this file in Python's own directory, and not from your current one.

What you could do is for example

```
path = os.path.abspath("..")
os.system('%s/bin/boxfit %s/settings/boxfitsettings2.txt | tee boxoutput.log' % (path, path))
```

To get the path of where you are at, then format that into your command

Comment: Note that `subprocess.call(args, shell=True)` is better than `os.system`…

Comment: That really depends. Also, I would use Popen for this.